# How to run stored procedure for every row on table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that accepts the following parameters

```
@Company_Move_From INT = NULL,
@Company_Move_To INT = NULL
```

I then have a table of data that looks like the below. This is my reference table which tells me which `OldCompanyIDs` need to be updated to the `NewCompanyID`.

```
OldCompanyID       NewCompanyID
-------------------------------
  11112               23847
  11113               23433
  11114               24652
```

Then I have my `CompanyTable`:

```
 CompanyID        CompanyName
 ----------------------------- 
   11112              TEST1
   11113              TEST2
   11114              TEST3
```

The stored procedure basically just updates the record on a company table. It will look for all records that match `@Company_Move_From`  and update them to `@Company_Move_To`.

What would be the best way to run this stored procedure for each row of my reference table above? I researched and found cursor suggestions but my understanding was that cursors can perform badly and best to avoid..

The stored procedure works fine, it's just getting it to run for every row on my reference table I am struggling with.

Any other suggestions on the most efficient way to run this?

Comment: So you have a company table with two ids? Or you have one companyID you need to update?

Comment: Instead of having a procedure that takes two paramters, have a procedure that takes a table-type paramter and then operate on all rows as a set.

Comment: @TomBoyd it is one table I need to update. The table I posted in my example is just the table that tells the stored procedure what it should be updated to.

So 11112 in my company table would become 23847 after the SP runs.. if that makes sense

Comment: I think you need to add more specifics, like, if there are two tables we're talking about here, then list them separately (the table that shows old/new mapping, and the table that is going to be affected by any update). And also whether you just want to update _everything in the mapping at one time_ or want to perform these updates conditionally. None of these things is very clear from the question right now. Maybe create a before and after [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you I have amended my post to hopefully make it more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a stored procedure? This SQL statement should do the update for you:

```sql
UPDATE Company
SET CompanyID  = NewCompanyID
FROM Company, ReferenceTable
WHERE Company.CompanyID = ReferenceTable.OldCompanyID;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Luuk It needs to be the stored procedure unfortunately as the stored procedure has other components that then update the ID's on other tables..

Comment: @marc_s: LOL I am using the link to bad habits too, and now I've done it meself... ≥